run CODA model error ——can not annotated celltype in images imagescope
During my CODA software, I found that I cannot annotate the TIFF files generated with ImageScope, and I am having trouble training the model correctly. Can you please give me more guidance? Thank you very much.
Firstly, I followed the steps(https://labs.pathology.jhu.edu/kiemen/wp-content/uploads/sites/39/2023/12/Instructions-for-applying-CODA.pdf
，download data from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K-wY_ArVGbEhebQD4AjOeERwx6-4Fw3G),
but the generated TIF file cannot be opened in ImageScope. I have downloaded the latest version of ImageScope. just like this（Attachment 1）:
enter image description here
Then,secondly, the TIF file generated by downsampling with OpenSlide also encountered issues when annotating cell types.
here is a more organized and clear description of your script using OpenSlide to produce a downsampled TIFF file:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

slide = openslide.OpenSlide('lungs_001-.ndpi')

target_mpp = 1.0 #

current_mpp_x = float(slide.properties[openslide.PROPERTY_NAME_MPP_X])
current_mpp_y = float(slide.properties[openslide.PROPERTY_NAME_MPP_Y])

scale_factor_x = current_mpp_x / target_mpp
scale_factor_y = current_mpp_y / target_mpp

level = slide.get_best_level_for_downsample(scale_factor_x)
downsample = slide.level_downsamples[level]

region = slide.read_region((0, 0), level, slide.level_dimensions[level])

region_rgb = region.convert("RGB")

region_np = np.array(region_rgb)

width, height = region.size
scaled_width = int(width * scale_factor_x)
scaled_height = int(height * scale_factor_y)

scaled_image = Image.fromarray(region_np).resize((scaled_width, scaled_height), Image.LANCZOS)

scaled_image.save('output_file.tiff', format='TIFF')

slide.close()

just like this（Attachment 2）:
enter image description here

However, I found that when I loop through the cells, the length is zero, indicating that the cells were not annotated successfully.
Could you please guide me on the steps for annotating cell types and training the model? I would greatly appreciate any assistance or feedback you could provide regarding these files. Thank you very much for your help.
